# Mysql: return true when all selected rows match a given criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, set

I have a table with the following structure:

```
order_rows(row_id, order_id, product_id, ordered_quantity, shipped_quantity)
```

and I wrote the following query to find if all the rows of a specific order has been shipped:

```
SELECT 1 = ALL (
    SELECT O.ordered_quantity = O.shipped_quantity
    FROM order_rows O
    WHERE O.order_id = 'INSERT_ORDER_ID_HERE'
) AS all_shipped
```

That query basically returns one column (all_shipped) filled with a TRUE if all the rows of the order has been completely shipped (FALSE otherwise).

In MySQL, is there any kind of a grouping function that returns true when all the matched elements are true ? 
I'm thinking of something like this:

```
SELECT ALL_TRUE(O.ordered_quantity = O.shipped_quantity) AS all_shipped
FROM order_rows O
WHERE O.order_id = 'INSERT_ORDER_ID_HERE'
```

That would return the same results of my first query.

If such function does not exists, is any other more *elegant* way to achieve this (i'm trying to get rid of the subquery)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS()` to test for un-shipped rows:

```
SELECT not exists (
  select *
  FROM order_rows O
  WHERE O.order_id = 'INSERT_ORDER_ID_HERE'
  AND O.ordered_quantity != O.shipped_quantity)
```

This will return `1` (true) if all rows are "shipped" or `0` (false) if not.

This should perform pretty well, because scanning should halt at the first row that isn't shipped.

Comment: I accepted your answer because your solution manages the fact that if there is no order_rows, the order can't be marked as "totally shipped" (because there were nothing to ship). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the reverse of what you did:

```
SELECT 0 = (SELECT Count(*) 
            FROM   order_rows O 
            WHERE  O.order_id = 'INSERT_ORDER_ID_HERE' 
                   AND O.ordered_quantity <> O.shipped_quantity) AS OK
```

Here the sub-query checks if there are any unshipped rows.
Having a sub-query here is quite OK, I think.
I would not try making this much more elegant.